# Parse query find and update multiple row

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using parse in a javascript application. I need to update multiple rows of a collection. With simple query I am getting the array of the rows. I can update the rows by running a save method within a forEach loop?

My question is "Is there any single query by which I can update multiple rows?" Like for mongodb we use update with multi true.

Please help.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like lamba expressions. But unfortunately there is not a good way of doing that. And by the way the lamba expression that would do the action you are seeking is probably the same as doing it with a foreach loop. Please provide some sample of your code!

Answer (score 0):

Get all the objects by querying, and update all the objects with the changes that you want to make.

Then use saveAll method

```
// save all the newly created objects
Parse.Object.saveAll(Results, {
     //Results is the array obtained after querying and updating the required fields
    success: function(objs) {
        // objects have been saved...
    },
    error: function(error) { 
        // an error occurred...
    }
});
```